# android webview for different size and dpi

Tags: android

By using WebView, I have loaded some html content contains image(large 
size, for example, 800*600) and text. 
For text, it can perform line wrapping automatically. 
But for image, it will enable the horizontal scroll even if 
"setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled" is set to false. 
Is there any method to force auto-fit in the WebView? 
Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately in webview, there is no way to just changes zoom for images and not text if that is what ur looking for

Comment: okay, then how can we put data of an epub book on webview ? I am trying to display content of epub book on web view but size of the page define in epub book in large than screen size so it get scroll how to prevent scroll and fit page on device according to device width.

Comment: thats the reason there are various ebook apps and not using webview

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the HTML content before loading it into the WebView and change the image(s) size according to screen resolution (that you can detect)